# Select based on neighbouring elements

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have some numpy array `myArr`. I know that I can easily selecet `myArr > x` to find the indices of elements that have a value above `x`.

How can I find indices of elements, where the *neighboring* elements are above `x`? For a 1d array, elements *neighboring* some `idx` are `(idx-1, idx+1)`. For an array of `d` dimensions, I mean neighboring in *any* dimension. That is, let `d=3`. The neighbors for `myArr[2, 2, 2]` are `[(1, 2, 2), (2, 1, 2), (2, 2, 1), (3, 2, 2), (2, 3, 2), (2, 2, 3)]`.

For example, take

```
import numpy as np
test = np.arange(4**2).reshape((4,4))
```

Here, we can graphically see the neighboring elements of `5` to be `[1, 4, 6, 9]`

```
test
Out[10]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])
```

I want to be able to select based on neighboring elements. For example, I want all indices, for which a neighboring element is `>= 9`. The following values would hold true in above example: `[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]` (`4` does not count as I defined neighboring not over diagonals.)

My expected output would then be the typical binary matrix:

```
neighboringIndicesLargerThan(myArr, 9)
array([[False, False, False, False],
   [False,  True,  True,  True],
   [ True,  True,  True,  True],
   [ True,  True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

Great if it works with any dimensions, but I need it to work at least on 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get mask of elements greater than the threshold and simply use [`binary_dilation`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_dilation.html) with an appropriate kernel to select north+east+west+south ones, like so -

```
In [20]: from scipy.ndimage.morphology import binary_dilation

In [21]: mask = test >= 9

In [22]: kernel = np.array([[0,1,0],[1,0,1],[0,1,0]])

In [23]: binary_dilation(mask, kernel)
Out[23]: 
array([[False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Just to ensure I understood the concept: If I add `[0, 0, 0]` to the kernel, it would also select if the element itself is >=9, even if neighboring are not?

Comment: @FooBar To select itself only, it would be : `kernel = np.array([[0,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,0]])`. The center of the kernel at (1,1) corresponds to the element itself.

Comment: @FooBar .. and that would be same as `mask`.